# How can I check Windows 10 driver's health (if they are corrupted)?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, crash, filesystem-corruption

recently my PC suffered from unexpected power off and, since then, some of the apps of my W10 computer started having frequent crashes. This behavior isn't new: up till 2 months ago I was facing the same issues and updating some of my drivers seems to have solved the problem. Since now the problem came back, I fear some drivers got corrupted.

Unfortunately, the same previous process won't help since updating to new versions is not what I need and there are no new versions of most of the drivers to being with. What I need is a way to reinstall my drivers to the same version they are now.

Of course, I could just go to Device Manager and uninstall and reinstall driver per driver but that is undesired: I don't know what could happen between uninstallation and reinstallation and it would take too much time. What I need is a tool that can check all my drivers's health and point me to which is faulty if any, so I can treat that problem specifically.

Searching on the web, I found out there is a Windows App called Verifier that allegedly does that. Trying to run it, though, only got my PC in restart loops; it didn't work. So, I came wanting to find other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, drivers do not corrupt if installed. There may be corrective updates available, or another driver (like BIOS) needs to be installed for the driver(s) to work correctly.

Get the manufacturer's driver update application and update all drivers including BIOS and Chipset.